# why the sum of nth step is $3^{n-1}(a+b)$ more than the sum of $n-1$ step!

Tags: sequences-and-series

consider two number $a$ and $b$,we make a sequence with special process,first step we sum $a$ and $b$,now we have three numbers $a$ ,$b$ and $a+b$,now we can make two other number by summing $a$ and $a+b$ we have $2a+b$ and $a+b$ and $b$ we have $a+2b$,it was second step.as you guess we repeat this process and produce other step,now if you omit $a$ and $b$ in each step and sum all numbers,you see the sum of nth step is $3^{n-1}(a+b)$ more than the sum of $n-1$ step!

now my question is why such a great thing happen?I mean something like a proof!

I attach some of my writing to make it clear.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can easily see that you add two adjacent terms from your table.
Except a and b everything is summed twice.So, the new numbers created will have sum twice the initial sum(without a and b) +a +b (as those are summed once).
So, $$
S_{new} =S_{old}+2S_{old}+a+b=3S_{old}+(a+b)$$
You can solve this to get$$
S_{n}=\frac{(3^n-1)}{2}(a+b)$$ which gives us$$
S_n-S_{n-1}=3^{n-1}(a+b)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that every element from the $(n-1)$-th step contributes three times to the sum of the $n$-th step except for $a$ and $b$ wich only contributes twice (can you se why?).

That means that if $S_n$ is the sum of the elements at the $n$-th step then:

$$S_n = 3S_{n-1} - (a+b) \\ S_1 = 2a+2b$$

Now you can prove using induction that:

$$S_n = (a+b) + 3(a+b) + 3^2(a+b) + \ldots 3^{n-1}(a+b) = (a+b)(1+3+3^2 + \ldots 3^{n-1}) = (a+b)\frac{3^n-1}{2}$$

Once you've done that (wich I leave to you), then $$S_n - S_{n-1} = 3S_{n-1} -(a+b) - S_{n-1} = \\2S_{n-1} -(a+b) = 2(a+b)\frac{3^{n-1}-1}{2} - (a+b) = 3^{n-1}(a+b)$$

As we wanted to prove.

Comment: actually the thing that I don't see is your question that you asked,I know the rest.